# Handlebars escape current context

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a web component in my handlebar template that has its own context e.g., this object `person{name: "singh"}` only exists within `<mycompnent></mycomponent>`.

I use `\{{person.name}}` to escape the default handlebar root context and use the local context inside the web component. This works `<mycompnent>\{{person.name}}</mycomponent>`.

However, I am not able to determine how to use this inside an if expression. My attempts like below all are resulting in error.

- `<mycompnent>{{#if \person.name }}<p>Good</p>{{/if}}</mycompnent>`
- `<mycompnent>{{#if (\person.name) }}<p>Good</p>{{/if}}</mycompnent>`
- `<mycompnent>{{#if \(person.name) }}<p>Good</p>{{/if}}</mycompnent>`

Full code block

```
<!-- This prints the root -->
    {{JSONstringify @root}}
    <ul>
        {{#each @root.data.items as |item|}}
        <li>
            <!-- mycomponent exposes a object named person inside the template-->
            <mycomponent id="{{item.ID}}">
               <template>

                <!-- This prints out the item object -->
                {{JSONstringify .}}
            
                <!-- This prints out the person object -->
                \{{person}}

                <!-- This print out the person name if it is set -->
                <p>\{{person.displayName}}</p>

                <!-- This results in error -->
                {{#if (\person.displayName) }}<p>\{{person.displayName}}</p>{{/if}}
            </template>
            </mycomponent>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is "the local context inside the web component"?

Comment: Ok...Please find bit more details added in my original post.

Comment: The `\` is for escaping Handlebars expressions so that they are not interpolated by the template execution - ie., the result of your template will include `{{person}}`. But this doesn't seem to be what you are describing, so I am confused.

Comment: Oh...Not sure if these details help. I need to escape person using \{{person}} inside <mycomponent> because code is in a Handlebars context and the default {{ }} is interpreted in the Handlebars context first, not <<mycomponent>> context.

Comment: Are you trying to have Handlebars leave the `{{#if}}`? As in: `\{{#if (person.displayName) }}<p>\{{person.displayName}}</p>\{{/if}}`?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for helping me. Within handlebars expression the person object does not exist i.e., {{person}} is null. However, person object does exist within <mycomponent> and i have been using the escape to get to it i.e., \{{person}} print out the object. Now problem for me is that not all properties of person are set and I don't want to print a blank property which means I must check if property exists. Any idea how could I escape a sub-expression or could I create local variable like x = \{{person}} and then use {{#if x.displayName}}<p>Display name: {{x.displayName}}</p>{{/if}}

Comment: I don't understand how your web component works. What does the work of interpolating `{{person}}`? It seems like you must have a templating engine like Handlebars.

Comment: Here is some context https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions/2199#discussioncomment-3138083

Comment: I don't know how to help you. This isn't a Handlebars question. Rather you want to know how to use conditionals in whatever templating language your web-component is using.

Comment: Oh, all good...Thank you for responding to my comments.